# Mount Return Code for CIFS mount

Tags: mount, cifs

When I run the following command (as root or via sudo) from a bash script I get an exit status (or return code in mount man page parlance) of 1:

mount -v -t cifs //nasbox/volume /tmpdir/ --verbose -o credentials=/root/cifsid &> /tmp/mylog

It outputs the following into the myflog file:

```
parsing options: rw,credentials=/root/cifsid

mount.cifs kernel mount options unc=//nasbox\volume,ip=192.168.1.1,user=root,pass=xxxx,ver=1,rw,credentials=/root/cifsid
```

It mounts the volume fine but returns the exit code (from the mount man page):

1 Incorrect invocation or permissions

The standard Linux log files don't contain any error information.  Hence, all seems to go well but I get an exit code of 1 instead of 0.  Any ideas?

The -v and --verbose options are just there for debugging this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anywhere in the [source code](http://sunsite.bilkent.edu.tr/pub/samba/sambaftp/cifs-cvs/mount.cifs.c) where it exits with exit code of 1 without printing an error message first.

If you are getting any error messages, you need to add them to your question.

This is probably a bug but I have not been able to find a likely bug report for it.

What operating system are you running, and version of mount.cifs.

EDIT:
Can you check the permissions are set so only root can read /root/cifsid as incorrect permissions may be causing this error.

Comment: I'm runing Samba (mount.cifs) 3.0.33 on Fedora 8.

Comment: Have not been able to find a relevant bug report so have stopped that line of investigation.

Comment: laikadad101, Was it a file permissions problem?

Comment: Permissions are set to 0600 and UID/GID set to 0 (root).

Comment: Try the command again and then check `dmesg | tail` to see if there is anything meaningful there.

Comment: No messages regarding this are listed with dmesg.

Comment: Sorry laikadad101, I am out of ideas. Submit a bug at https://bugzilla.samba.org/